# How to get php form data to pdf in table structure using WAMP

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I am displaying all the users in the form using php where the data are fetched from db.

When i click on the icon all users data should be show in a pdf with a good **table structure.**

**i am hereby using fpdf to generate it. i created pdf but the records are not in formatted structure.**

How should this can be done.

kindly advice.

thanks in advance
strong text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done only by using dompdf. Here is the link.

http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/examples.php#demo

and i got the exact output what i need.

thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

Please try to put the full code which you are using to create the PDF, using fpdf.

I would also recommend that you please try using the [DOMPDF](http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/) library, as I used it myself several times & had no such problem with table structuring.

Maybe the HTML part of the PDF code is not correct, so please put the code in your question.